Angular momentum ABOUT centre of mass (Investigating this IITJEE 2016 problem.....)
Note- By COM i mean the Centre of mass.
In this question , I analyzed a problem in mechanics and encountered a difficult situation which the problem doesn't address (and so do my teachers  ) ......
What i have been taught about the net angular momentum of a system is that -
$$\vec{L}_{Net}=\vec{L}_{ of COM}+\vec{L}_{About COM}$$
Now here the $$\vec{L}_{ of COM}$$ is simple enough to calculate in most cases because COM is a point and so we need to consider only a translatory frame of reference
But the $$\vec{L}_{About COM}$$ doesnt seem to only include spin angular momentum but also the rotational effects too ( though i am not very clear why that is true)
So consider the following situation
Image link- https://i.stack.imgur.com/KofaA.jpg
source- JEE adv 2016 Physics
I am having a problem imagining how the situation would be in COM's frame of reference
My guess is that both $$\omega _{s}$$ and $$\omega _{o}$$ would exist but again i am unable to reason it
Also How will the discs move (in frame of COM) ? Imean will they revolve (like planets somewhat ) about COM ? and if they do so ,  about which axis will they revolve ?
I am trying to find the angular momentum about COM through this
Image link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4kbp.jpg
[Relative frame of COM]
On a side note-  the official JEE advanced problem was this (Image attached)
the common solution was this -  everyone took  $$\vec{L}_{About COM}=\omega _{s}\cdot I_{rod}$$  , thereby [i]ignoring[/i] the fact that  the effect due to  $$\omega _{o}$$ ALSO exists
(This is my doubt - HOW do we calculate the actual $$\vec{L}_{About COM}$$ in which BOTH omegas are used? )
The examination has an option (option -C) which exactly matches with the answer optained using the common incorrect equation and student were only expected to reason out that the option was incorrect . They did not need to find the actual answer
However my doubt is How do calculate the actual $$\vec{L}_{About COM}$$
(PS - Actually the official key gave that option  (option-C) as correct to as most couldnt reason this out  - Though definitely it is incorrect )


This is indeed a tricky question. Since there are two non-perpendicular angular velocities, the total angular velocity about an axis is not the same as the spin about that axis. You have be very careful with the components.

Please dont close this post ... The question is perfectly legitimate and is Not a homework related one. I have posted this after not receiving much valuable help from my professor....

I recommend rewording it such that it asks about concepts rather than the solution. Once you are ready, tick the box to submit for review.

@vincent thacker    Can you please tell where i can find this "box" that must be ticked for review?

First go to the edit page by clicking Edit. Then the checkbox will be at the bottom next to the Save Edits button.
